# What's the difference between cluster_primary_security_group_id and cluster_security_group_id in terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cluster-computing, amazon-eks

From the doc of terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws, it says there are two outputs named cluster_primary_security_group_id and cluster_security_group_id.

```
cluster_primary_security_group_id
Description: The cluster primary security group ID created by the EKS cluster on 1.14 or 
later. Referred to as 'Cluster security group' in the EKS console.

cluster_security_group_id
Description: Security group ID attached to the EKS cluster. On 1.14 or later, this is the 
'Additional security groups' in the EKS console.
```

After creating the cluster, I do see two different security groups, what's the difference between these two security group?

Link of the doc: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest?tab=outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EKS uses [two security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sec-group-reqs.html):

**Cluster security group used with k8s 1.14**

> A cluster security group is designed to **allow all traffic from the control plane and managed node groups to flow freely between each other**. By assigning the cluster security group to the elastic network interfaces created by Amazon EKS that allow the control plane to communicate with the managed node group instances, you don't need to configure complex security group rules to allow this communication. Any instance or network interface that is assigned this security group can freely communicate with other resources with this security group.

**Control plane security group with k8s earlier then 1.14**

> For Amazon EKS clusters created earlier than Kubernetes version 1.14 and platform version eks.3, **control plane to node communication was configured by manually creating a control plane security group** and specifying that security group when you created the cluster. At cluster creation, this security group was then attached to the network interfaces created by Amazon EKS that allow communication between the control plane and the nodes.

Comment: @AlexW No problem. Glad it helped.